# MVC4: How to send form parameter from view to controller?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

Browse action:

```
public ActionResult Browse(int? Category, string sortOrder, string currentFilter, string searchString, int? page)
```

I could send category id using action link

```
@Html.ActionLink("Name", "Browse", new { sortOrder = ViewBag.NameSortParm, currentFilter=ViewBag.CurrentFilter, Category=ViewBag.CategoryId })
```

How to pass category id from form to controller?

```
<div id="search">
        @using (Html.BeginForm("Browse", "Home", FormMethod.Get))
        {
        @Html.TextBox("SearchString", ViewBag.CurrentFilter as string)
        <input type="submit" value="Search" />
        }
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can send it in a hidden input:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Browse", "Home", FormMethod.Get))
{
    @Html.TextBox("SearchString", ViewBag.CurrentFilter as string)
    @Html.Hidden("Category",ViewBag.CategoryId)
    <input type="submit" value="Search" />
}
```

Comment: Instead of this line:@Html.Hidden("Category",ViewBag.CategoryId) I used this code:int CategoryId = ViewBag.CategoryId;
            @Html.Hidden("Category", CategoryId); Because it has error for dynamic ViewBag.CategoryId.

Comment: Casting the ViewBag result could be an option as well. `@Html.Hidden("Category", (int?)ViewBag.CategoryId)` in order to skip doing `int CategoryId = ViewBag.CategoryId;`